# Calculate Symbol-Size From Linker-Map-File

Tags: c++, linker, arm, ld, binary-size

I'm trying to understand linker map files. This is the beginning of my text-section:

```
.text           0x08000400    0x14ba0
                0x08000400                . = ALIGN (_flash_alignment)
 *(.text)
 .text          0x08000400       0x40 .../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/thumb/v7e-m+dp/hard/crtbegin.o
 .text          0x08000440     0x5ee4 .../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/thumb/v7e-m+dp/hard\libstdc++.a(cp-demangle.o)
                0x0800623c                __cxa_demangle
                0x08006300                __gcclibcxx_demangle_callback
```

I used [amap](https://www.sikorskiy.net/info/prj/amap/) to analyze the map file and it reported a size of 196 bytes for `__cxa_demangle` and 24096 bytes for `__gcclibcxx_demangle_callback`.

I thought it works like this:

All the symbols from `cp-demangle.o` start at address `0x08000440` and there are a total of `0x5ee4` addresses used for all contained symbols.
`__cxa_demangle` starts at address `0x0800623c` and ends at `0x08006300 - 1`, so it has a size of 196 bytes.

So far, so good - this is matching what amap reported. But **how is the size of `__gcclibcxx_demangle_callback` calculated?**

If it starts at `0x8006300` and the whole section for `cp-demangle.o` ends at `0x08000440 + 0x5ee4 = 0x08006324`, then `__gcclibcxx_demangle_callback` would have a size of `0x08006324 - 0x08006300 = 0x24` bytes. This is far off of the results yielded by amap.

Another thing that I don't understand is: **What fills the memory between the start of the section at `0x08000440` and the start of `__cxa_demangle` at `0x0800623c`?** At the end of the day, the reported sizes from amap (196 bytes and 24096 bytes) sum up to 24292 which is the same 0x5ee4 (== number of adresses) that is written in the mapfile.

Comment: Your analysis seems reasonable - I suspect amap is not doing its calculations correctly.

Comment: The most likely answer to your second question is that it is (static scope) code that is called by __cxa_demangle and __gcclibcxx_demangle_callback.